# Implementing same behavior between Enums : this static method cannot hide the instance method from interface

Tags: java, enums

I have a common process with different progress values and step number, depending on the user.

To solve this I've made an interface :

```
public interface Progress {
    int getTotalStepNumber();
    int getIndex();
    String getMessage();
    @Override
    String toString();
}
```

So a step process implementation is like this, litteraly, it is an enumeration of the steps for this process :

```
public enum ProgressImplementationOfProcessOne implements Progress {

    STEP_ONE(1, "Step one message."),
    STEP_TWO(2, "Step two message.");
    // ... etc. with more steps

    /**
     * Number of steps for this process.
     */
    private static final int STEPS = 2;

    private int index;
    private String message;

    ProgressImplementationOfProcessOne(int index, String message) {
        this.index = index;
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public int getTotalStepNumber() { return STEPS; }

    @Override
    public int getIndex() { return this.index; }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() { return this.message; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return this.message; }
}
```

But then I thought it would be nice to find the corresponding step from implementation as well, with the method `valueOf()` of enumerations. So I added the following lines to my interface :

```
default Progress valueOf(String s) {
    for (Progress progress : this.getValues()) {
        if (progress.getMessage().equals(s)) {
            return progress
        }
    }
    return null;
}
default Progress valueOf(int i) {
    for (Progress progress : this.getValues()) {
        if (progress.getIndex() == this.getIndex()) {
            return progress;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Since there is no `getValues()` method in the interface `Progress` I added the following method to it (thinking "the enum implementation will handle it natively").

```
default List<Progress> getValues() { return null; }
```

But I don't understand why I get this error for each `ProgressImplementation` : 
`This static method cannot hide the instance method from Progress.`.

I know I could do it by creating an additional `class ProgressStep` which replace an enum value, and replace enum by classes with attributes and so on, but since enum can handle multiple values I thought it could have been easier with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply rename the `valueOf` to something like `valueOfEnum`, as `valueOf` is already specified by `java.lang.Enum`.

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(Class<T> enumType,
                                            String name) {
    T result = enumType.enumConstantDirectory().get(name);
    if (result != null)
        return result;
    if (name == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("Name is null");
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "No enum constant " + enumType.getCanonicalName() + "." + name);
}
```

The comment on that method contains following section:

> Note that for a particular enum type T, the **implicitly declared public static T valueOf(String)** method on that enum may be used instead of this method to mapfrom a name to the corresponding enum constant. All theconstants of an enum type can be obtained by calling the implicit public static T[] values() method of that type

<sub>Emphasis mine</sub>

As you can see, `valueOf(String s)` is already declared on every enum class which in turn is the reason, you can't have it in an interface on any enum

Comment: Nevermind, I would not have to duplicate the same logic of iterating through enum and compare by calling the same two getters, but since it is not possible I will follow your suggestion. Thanks for your answer.